# How do I configure meta tags for a panel page?

Tags: 8, panels, meta-tags

How do I configure meta tags for a panel page? I want to change title, keywords and description.

Ideally I want to use Yoast.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same requirement and one of the patches attached in the issue titled "[Panels / Page Manager integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2563657)" worked for me. This patch basically adds a module of panel pages which when enabled, provides interface to configure meta tags for each panel pages under `/admin/config/search/metatag`.

Answer (score 0):

If it might help someone, specific panel pages meta descriptions are available under `/admin/structure/pages`, find your page and edit the tab Meta tags.